# Function dependent on another function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function

How do i get rid of an identifier not found error?

For example:

```
int step1(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == a)
    {
        cout << "They are the same." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        step2(a, b);
    }
}

int step2(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        a = a - b;
        step1(a, b);
    }
    if (b > a)
    {
        b = b - a;
        step1(a, b);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    step1(a, b);
}
```

If the code was setup like the example above a runtime error of 'step1':identifier not found would appear, but if I were to place the step2 function above the step1 function, then a runtime error of 'step2':identifier not found would appear. How might I change this so that there aren't any errors in the future?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple C++ Error: "... undeclared (first use this function)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354522/simple-c-error-undeclared-first-use-this-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a forward declaration for `f2` at the top of the file.
As an example:

```
int step2(int a, int b);

int step1(int a, int b)
{
    // your code that uses step2 here
}

int step2(int a, int b)
{
    // your code that uses step1 here
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    step1(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Forward Declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)

You have to add `int step2(int a,int b);` before `int step1(int a, int b)`

During compilation, when compiler compiles `step1`, it doesn't know the identifier `step2`. So you have to declare the function before hand.