# C++, Undeclared ( first use of this function )

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a very simple program where the user can choose how big of a matrix to create  after which it is filled with random numbers and is printed out. Super simple stuff, but still causing trouble for me as a newbie. I have tried all kinds of solutions, with different error codes and have now arrived to this error code which i can't seem to solve no matter how much i google...

The error message in detail:

> error: 'doJob' undeclared (first use this function)
>   error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)

I have tried different ways of solving this based on some google searching i've been doing, but it all seems to result in to a different problem. If this problem is solved somewhere else, please point me in the right direction.

> header file

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

void doJob(int x, int y);

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

> main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {

int row, column;

cout<<"Please enter the number of rows for your matrix";
cin>>row;

cout<<"Please enter the number of columns for you matrix";
cin>>column;

doJob(row, column); // this is where the error shows up

}
```

> secondary file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

void doJob (int row, int column)
{ codecodecode...
```

Comment: I believe that matrix.h is already a library (see [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Matrix/Matrix.h)).

Comment: Also, how are you compiling this? It should theoretically work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple C++ Error: "... undeclared (first use this function)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354522/simple-c-error-undeclared-first-use-this-function)

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Check for typos and duplication of `MATRIX_H`.

Comment: Try #pragma once rather than a guard #ifdef and see if that fixes it.  If so, MATRIX_H is defined somewhere else.

Comment: If MATRIX_H is defined somewhere else, you can define it yourself in `main file` and the compiler will tell you where the other definition is.  (Of course you throw away the forced definition after you solve the problem.)

Comment: How about adding `extern void doJob(int, int);` in the secondary file?