# How Do I Pass Parameters From One Function to Another in C++

Tags: c++, function, ascii

It's my first post using StackOverflow; I figured I should get used to using this website since I'm interested in programming now...

Anyway, I'm taking a C++ class right now, and we were given the option to have an open ended program in which the user chooses from a menu (switch statement) that calls functions based on which choice the user put in.

Here, I'm trying to have the user's first choice display a product using a function called multiply when given an input for length and an input for width. The hard part is trying to display a rectangle made out of asterisks (*) that correspond to the length and width.

I'm having trouble figuring out how I would get void drawRect() to obtain the values length and width. Is this what "passing a parameter" is? And if so, should I make drawRect() an integer return type?

Any suggestions on how I should be approaching this?

```
void displayMenu();


int multiply(int, int);
void drawRect();

int main()
{
    int userChoice = 0;
    do
    {
        displayMenu();

        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> userChoice;

        switch (userChoice)
        {
        // display the area of a rectangle
            case 1:
            {
                int length, width;
                cout << "Enter a length: ";
                cin >> length;
                cout << "Enter a width: ";
                cin >> width;
                cout << "The area of the rectangle is: " << multiply(length, width) << endl << endl;
                drawRect(length, width);
                break;
            }
    }


int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    int product = x * y;
    return product;
}
void drawRect(int length, int width)
{
    // draw the top row
    cout << setfill('*') << setw(width) << endl;

    // draw the middle rows

    // draw the bottom row
    cout << setfill('*') << setw(width) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You only need `drawRect` to return something if you need to use the result of `drawRect` (whatever that would be) in your `main` function (or in whichever other function might call `drawRect`). Currently your `drawRect` function takes two parameters, `length` and `width`. What textbook are you using in the class?

Comment: Oh I see, you have `drawRect(int, int)` *defined* below, you have `drawRect()` *declared* above. In C++, a unique function is defined by a combination of its name and its parameter types. `drawRect()` and `drawRect(int, int)` are two COMPLETELY different functions as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: Are you currently getting a compiler error?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354522/simple-c-error-undeclared-first-use-this-function

Comment: @John I'm using C++ From Control Structures through Objects, Ninth Edition by Tony Gaddis

Comment: Looks like the chapter on functions in general starts on page 299, but I don't have access to the book so I can't see what specific concepts are on which pages. You want to look for the terms "prototype" and "forward declaration", which is what you're doing, in the index.

Comment: And please answer the question: "are you currently getting a compiler error?"

Answer (score 0):

> Is this what "passing a parameter" is?

Yes.

> And if so, should I make drawRect() an integer return type?

No. `drawRect(int length, int width)` only will send asterisks to `cout` so you can see it in output

> Any suggestions on how I should be approaching this?

As already mentioned, this will not compile as-is. Your function `drawRec(int length, int width)` is used before it is declared. Declaring `void drawRect();` near the top is a good first step, but you need to add the parameters in like you have it below when its called. I would recommend using a loop (`for`, `while`, etc) to iterate over the rectangles length to print out a row of asterisks each time through the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    // draw a row of *'s
    cout << setfill('*') << setw(width) << endl;
}
```